# RunBase implementation

Tags: axapta, x++

I am learning Ax2012, I use Microsoft training material. I am trying to implement RunBase class using QueryRun without a dialog.

I have a classDeclaration as follow:

```
class SalesCalcAverageSalesPriceNoDialog extends RunBase
{
    FromDate fromDate;
    ToDate toDate;
    ItemId itemId;
    QueryRun queryRun;
    #DEFINE.CurrentVersion(1)
    #LOCALMACRO.CurrentList
    #ENDMACRO
}
```

Then I override initParmDefault()

```
public void initParmDefault()
{
    Query query;
    QueryBuildDataSource qbds;
    QueryBuildRange qr;
    super();
    query = new Query();
    qbds = query.addDataSource(tableNum(CustInvoiceTrans));
    qbds.addRange(fieldNum(CustInvoiceTrans, InvoiceDate));
    qr.value("28/9/2012");
    qbds.addRange(fieldNum(CustInvoiceTrans, InvoiceDate));
    qr.value("4/8/2015");
    queryRun = new QueryRun(query);
}
```

Then i override pack() method which I return conNull(), unpack() method which I return true for simplicity. In run() method, I have :

```
public void run()
{
    CustInvoiceTrans custInvoiceTrans;
    SalesPrice salePrice;
    Qty qty;
    while(queryRun.next())
    {
        custInvoiceTrans = queryRun.get(tableNum(CustInvoiceTrans));
        salesPrice += custInvoiceTrans.SalesPrice;
        qty += custInvoiceTrans.Qty;
    }
    info(strFmt("avg is %1", salesPrice/qty));
}
```

When i try to run the class, I got the message of queryRun not initialized. But I did initialize the queryRun in the initParmDefault() and from the training material, it says the RunBase framework calles the initPArmDEfault() method when initializing a new object of RunBase.

Can someone help me point out what I have done wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `RunBase` framework has no `queryRun` variable (that is why you have to define the variable in the class declaration). Instead it uses method `queryRun` to get the `QueryRun` instance. This method is implemented in class `RunBase` and returns `null`, which in turn causes the "queryRun not initialized" message.

To resolve this problem, you have to overwrite the `queryRun` method in your class so that it returns the `queryRun` variable of your class instead of `null`. See class `Tutorial_RunbaseForm` for an example.

Please be aware that the use of the [RunBase Framework is deprecated for AX 2012](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn527190.aspx). Use the [SysOperation Framework](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg862488.aspx) instead.

Comment: Ahh, so that's what queryRun() method is for. I thought that method was just like a getter to expose member variables in class so I didn't implement it since queryRun was still in scope. Thank you for pointing that out!

Comment: Also `initParmDefault` is only called when `unpack` returns false.

Comment: @JanB.Kjeldsen: In the training material that I have, in the lab, it returns conNull() for pack() method, and true for unpack() method. However, in the introduction part, it does more than that e.g. like return #CurrentVersion, chekc for version,... So, what is the good practice for this scenario?

Comment: Take a look at the Pack-Unpack Design Pattern (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa879675.aspx)

Comment: `RunBase` is not depricated, `FormLetter` is! The title of the linked article imprecise to put it mildly.

Comment: @JanB.Kjeldsen: Do you base this only on the sentence with the word formletter in the article? Or do you have further information that `RunBase` is only deprecated for the `FormLetter` framework, but not in general? I'm wondering because in the [SysOperation Framework Overview](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg862488.aspx) article it also says that this framework replaces `RunBase` (`FormLetter` is not mentioned there).

Comment: "Yes. The feature has been removed, and a replacement feature is available." This can clearly not be RunBase. Also, I have yet to see thousands of descendants of the RunBase class go away. It will not even happen in the forthcoming version of AX.